# How do I get selenium WebDriver in Python to wait for 5 minutes after a particular form submission?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I don't want to change the implicit wait for the WebDriver, because this problem happens only on a particular click.

**Please Note: There is no code executed after the click statement. This isn't the usual wait failure. I tried adding a simple "print("test") after the driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click() but execution fails at the click itself. The print is not executed. Webdriver times out while waiting for the page to load (upwards of 5 minutes).**

I need to submit a particular form. This form takes a lot of time after clicking on the submit button. It can take upto 5 minutes to load the next page.

> WebDriver times out after clicking this button with a "TimeOut"
>   exception.

Here is the stack trace:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "C:/Users/user.domain/PycharmProjects/server_config/server_config.py",
>   line 704, in 
>           # Apply the reset
>         File "C:/Users/user.domain/PycharmProjects/server_config/server_config.py",
>   line 222, in server_reset
>           logger.info("Resetting the server config")
>         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 80, in click
>           self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
>         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 501, in _execute
>           return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 308, in execute
>           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>         File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 194, in check_response
>           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
>         (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows
>   NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)

Sometimes the page errors out and doesn't even show the landing page. On other occasions it takes 5 minutes or even more.

How can I handle this particular click? What is a more elegant way to handle the wait request instead of changing the implicit wait values before and after this click?

Comment: You can write a small loop where it will wait for the element to be present(which should be present after the form submission). If the element is not present wait more  - a thread.sleep for few minutes otherwise it will come out of the loop

Comment: if there is a loader image, then we can wait for loader image to disappear, so that, webdriver session wouldn't be timeout.

Comment: @Neha I thought of that but the timeout error occurs at the click instruction itself. It doesn't even go to the next instruction. There is no way to get the wait code executed if I write that after the click.

Comment: @Murthi There is no loader image. But the problem isn't that simple. I can write a wait for a particular element but the timeout occurs at the click itself. Python doesn't even execute a print statement after that click().

Comment: can u add a thread.sleep immediately after the click statement and then check

Comment: @Neha Thanks for suggesting. I've already tried with time.sleep(300) in Python and that didn't work either. The problem is that for the sleep to work, Python has to execute that code. The code is NOT executed after the click. It doesn't matter what we write after the click because that is not getting executed. We can only do something before making that click. Sorry about this complication but this is how this webpage is. :(

Comment: the timeout here is pageload timeout... it's not timing out on the click.  Selenium will already be waiting for pageready event.  The pageload timeout is global, and defaults vary by browser/driver.  Btw, if it takes 5 minutes to submit a form, seems like something needs fixin'.

Comment: if this is a large file upload they should consider posting it to an iframe and providing some feedback on the main page.  That would also avoid Selenium having to wait for a pageload.

Comment: @pcalkins Yes. Something in the background processes does need fixing. However, management doesn't care about the quality for this particular page (because it's internal). I'm okay to wait that long but I just need the automation script to work over here. I think "guy"'s answer below is the best solution I've found so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`implicit wait` doesn't effect the page load, it's only relevant to locating web elements with `find_element()` functions.

You can use `driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)` to increase the time the driver awaits the page to load (although according to the [w3c specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#timeouts) the default value is already 5 minutes).

In case the page doesn't load at all you can use `try except` if you wish to do something else than terminating with exception

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
except TimeoutException:
    print('Failed to load next page')
    # do something
    # or rethrow the exception with 'raise'
```

Comment: Although I wanted to avoid changing the timeout value manually, using a try except works for me.  I'll try changing the page_load_timeout to a higher value later and report back on this. Thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 0):

I meant something like:

```
   WebElement.click();
  int counter = 0;
  do
    {

      switch (elementStatus)
      {
        case "Element is not present":

          Thread.sleep(100000);
          counter++;
          if (counter == 4)
            throw new AutomationException("Form submission is taking time. Please check manually.");
          break;

        case "Element is present":
          counter = 4;
          break;

      }

    } while (counter < 4);
```

Comment: I tried this code. It still fails at "WebElement.click();". Actually that is driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").click() . But that's okay. There is no code executed after that "click" method. After making the click the page starts loading (the browser shows page is loading but we are still on the same page for 5 minutes). In the meanwhile, Selenium times out.

Comment: Try a sleep immediately after driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").click() .

Answer (score 0):

Check for the html element which exists in the case of both successful and invalid form submission,if it exists wait for that particular html element state/value change.

For example , below code is in java.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(<message>)));
String result = null;

if(element.isDisplayed() && element.getText().contains("Successfully"))
     result = driver.findElement(By.id(<name>)).getText();
else
    result = element.getText();
```

Comment: The problem is that any code after the click doesn't get executed. Python has to execute that code. The code is NOT executed after the click. It doesn't matter what we write after the click because that is not getting executed. Python is busy executing selenium's "click()" method. The page loads for 5 minutes. Normally, we can wait for individual AJAX elements after the page loads. But over here, the page itself is stuck on loading. Selenium times out on the page load. We can only do something before making that click. Sorry about this complication but this is how this webpage is. :(